# C++ / Is the wrong parameter of typedef causing a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, shared-ptr, typedef

Is the wrong parameter of typedef causing a memory leak?
The follow code create Memory leak

we have
**Example Class A**

**implA.cpp**

```
void example_funcA(
const std::shared_ptr<A>& object,
const std::function<void(void)>& next) 
{
  ... 
  next(); 
  ...
}

...

void example_funcB(const std::shared_ptr<A>& object)
{...}
```

**implB.cpp** / We did the wrong coding at first. **typedef FuncA**

```
auto implA_ = std::make_shared<implA>(.....);
typedef void (implA::*FuncB)(const std::shared_ptr<A>&);

typedef std::function<void(void)> Func;

typedef void (implA::*FuncA)(
      const std::shared_ptr<A>&,
      std::function<void(void)>);

  auto next = (Func)std::bind((FuncB)&implA::example_funcB, implA_, object);

  implA_->async(std::bind((FuncA)&implA::example_funcA, implA_, object, next));
```

This code fails to delete the object of class A by smart pointer and causes memory leak.

But we modified the code.

```
typedef void (implA::*FuncA)(
      const std::shared_ptr<A>&,
      std::function<void(void)>);
-> fix code
typedef void (implA::*FuncA)(
      const std::shared_ptr<A>&,
      const std::function<void(void)>&);
```

This code removes the object of class A as a smart pointer we want.

**The point of the question is this. Whether the use of an incorrect typedef affects the smart pointer's reference count, and if it is possible to run out of memory at the end of the operation.**

Comment: It would improve the question to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Just post the program that you think has the problem. You do not need to post the alternative,correct code

Comment: You should not use C-style casts as they have many instances of causing silent undefined behaviour when used incorrectly. If you need a cast there (to disambiguate an overloaded function) , use `static_cast`

Comment: Also make sure your example is compilable *verbatim*.

Comment: A cast is programmer's way to tell the compiler "shut up, I know what I'm doing". But the compiler has many ways to tell the programmer "no pal, you don't".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've entered the world of undefined behavior. Your example_funcA has signature:

```
  void(const std::shared_ptr<A>&, const std::function<void(void)>&)
```

but you are casting it to:

```
 void(const std::shared_ptr<A>&, std::function<void(void)>)
```

before invoking it. This makes the compiler think it needs to copy the second argument as it expects it to be passed by value when really example_funcA expects a const reference. The mismatch between how the compiler sets up (and copies) the argument and what the method actually expects is probably causing the copy to be lost and thus a leak. As you are binding your shared_ptr to example_funcB, the binding captures the shared_ptr and it is this capture that is specifically leaking.

As someone already commented you should avoid C style casts as you will get no protection from the compiler using them. Prefer static_cast<> or no cast where you can.